# Get a string from xml files

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

i have a coode that are trying to get the id of xml file where url exist.

My code

```
    public static string GetPageIdByUrl(string url)
{
    string folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/Pages/" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        var xml = XDocument.Load(file);

        var q = from f in xml.Descendants("Page")
                where (string)f.Element("Url").Value == url
                select (string)f.Attribute("Id").Value;

        if (q.Count() != 0)
        {
            return q.SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }

    return null;
 }
```

I get this error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Line: select f.Attribute("Id").Value;

if "test" exist in a xml file `<Url>test</Url>` i want it to return the attribute ID. But that sems only work for the first xml file.

Hope you get the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mabye tirred today,the problem was that in the xml file the attribute was calld "id" and not "Id".

Comment: You should put this as and "EDIT:" in your original question rather than a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try posting some sample XML.

I'm guessing your Url element doesn't have an "Id" (exact spelling) attribute. Therefore the XNode is null and cannot provide a Value.

Answer (score 1):

Is `Id` an attribute on the `Url` element?

```
<Pages>
    <Page><Url Id="6428">http://www.example.com/</Url></Page>
</Pages>
```

Then you need something like this:

```
var q = from f in xml.Descendants("Page")
        where (string)f.Element("Url") == url
        select (string)f.Element("Url").Attribute("Id");
```

(Note that you can leave out `.Value` when using casts as XElement and XAttribute define casts to various base types. This is often a source of unexpected NullReferenceExceptions.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using XPath instead?

It's been a while since I've used the syntax, but the query should look something similar to this:

> /Page[Url='THE_STRING']

Using SelectNodes(), you should get a list of nodes that fit to your query, and from whom you could get the attribute's value.